# Remove Python 2 remnants

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm in the process of removing Python 2 support for many of my projects and I'd like to remove the Python 2 cruft that has build up over the years. I'm talking, for example, about the

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

headers, the `object` specification in

```
class Foobar(object):
    # ...
```

or the imports from `__future__` and `six`.

How can I best find/remove those things?

Comment: Does the `2to3.py` script available in Python release not solving the issues? [Here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html) is the official documentation.

Comment: @AmeyaVS No. `2to3` _adds_ Python 3 support. I want to _remove_ Python 2 support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [pyupgrade](https://pypi.org/project/pyupgrade/) tool does a great job of removing old cruft you no longer need. It supports upgrading to either Python 3+, 3.6+, or 3.7+, removing more and more cruft the newer version you can require.

The pyupgrade readme has an overview of what it fixes, which includes the `coding` header, the `object` superclass, unneeded `__future__` imports, and many uses of the `six` library.

Notably, it does not remove the use of the `future` library.